# Setting averages for each day in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, date

I have a system that relies on, among other things, higher than average volume to trigger an alert. My database was hacked and the existing averages are not right. That is the answer to why I need such a thing. I want to SET the average volume for each date going back to 1/1/2014.

I've tried the following variations (and then some) of SELECT statements to test out but I keep getting either a single date of data, or every day's total volume rather than a 30/60/90 day average for each date:

```
SELECT  `date`, AVG(`total_volume`) AS 'avg_volume' FROM `table`WHERE `symbol`= "ABCD" AND `date`> (`date`-90);

SELECT  `date` , AVG(  `total_volume` ) AS  'avg_volume' FROM  `table` WHERE  `symbol` =  "ABCD" GROUP BY  `date` -90;

SELECT  `date` , AVG( `total_volume` ) AS  'avg_volume'  FROM  `table` WHERE  `symbol` =  "ABCD" AND  `date` >  `date` -90 GROUP BY  `date` ORDER BY  `date` DESC;

SELECT  `date` , AVG( SUM(`total_volume`) ) AS  'avg_volume'  FROM  `table` WHERE  `symbol` =  "ABCD" AND  `date` >  `date` -90 GROUP BY  `date` ORDER BY  `date` DESC;

SELECT  `date` , SUM(  `total_volume` ) /30 AS  'avg_volume' FROM  `table` WHERE  `symbol` =  "ABCD";

SELECT  `date` , SUM(  `total_volume` ) /90 AS  'avg_volume' FROM  `table` WHERE  `symbol` =  "ABCD" GROUP BY  `date` -90 ORDER BY `date` DESC;

SELECT  `date` , SUM(  `total_volume` ) /90 AS  'avg_volume' FROM  `table` WHERE  `symbol` =  "ABCD" AND  `date` BETWEEN  `date` -90 AND `date` GROUP BY  `date` ORDER BY  `date` DESC;

SELECT  `date` , AVG(  `total_volume` ) AS  'avg_volume' FROM  `table` WHERE  `symbol` =  "ABCD" AND  `date` BETWEEN  `date` -90 AND `date` GROUP BY  `date` -90 ORDER BY  `date` DESC;

SELECT  `date` , AVG(  `total_volume` ) AS  'avg_volume' FROM  `table` WHERE  `symbol` =  "ABCD" AND  `date` BETWEEN  `date` -90 AND `date` GROUP BY  `date` -90 ORDER BY  `date` BETWEEN  `date` -90 AND `date`  DESC;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I think we are close with that, but that gives us the forward average rather than what the average was on the specific date . the only way I see that may actually work is this:  SET 'avg_volume' =  (SELECT AVG(`total_volume`)  WHERE `date`BETWEEN "20150526" AND "20150826" GROUP BY `symbol` ) WHERE `date` = '20150826'...and then the ridiculous task of going back 2 years, and running the command for each and every day....there must be an easier way...

Answer (score 0):

If you can share schema of your table, some sample data and expected result, then that'd be very helpful in giving a precise answer. But if you need to find the average of total_volume for every date, try this

```
SELECT YEAR(`date`) as 'year', DAY(`date`) as 'day', `date`, AVG(`total_volume`) as 'avg_volume' FROM `table` WHERE `symbol` = "ABCD" AND `date` > '2014-01-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY 1, 2
```

If you need an average of monthly, two monthly and three monthly then try following

Monthly:

```
SELECT YEAR(`date`) as 'year', MONTH(`date`) as 'month', `date`, AVG(`total_volume`) as 'avg_volume' FROM `table` WHERE `symbol` = "ABCD" AND `date` > '2014-01-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Bi-Monthly:

```
SELECT YEAR(`date`) as 'year', CEIL(MONTH(`date`)/2) as 'bimonth', `date`, AVG(`total_volume`) as 'avg_volume' FROM `table` WHERE `symbol` = "ABCD" AND `date` > '2014-01-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Quarterly:

```
SELECT YEAR(`date`) as 'year', CEIL(MONTH(`date`)/3) as 'quarter', `date`, AVG(`total_volume`) as 'avg_volume' FROM `table` WHERE `symbol` = "ABCD" AND `date` > '2014-01-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY 1, 2
```

I used [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,222945,223012#msg-223012) to come up with the idea

Comment: I'm sorry, please bear with me. I was hacked again twice this week and I'm dealing with that crisis, but I am aware that this is open until I respond with schema.